# SQL - join with itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `t1` as below

```
 -----------------------------
 |    date   |  id   | value |
 -----------------------------
 | 2/28/2019 |  1    | abc1  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  2    | abc2  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  3    | abc3  |
 | 2/27/2019 |  1    | abc4  |
 | 2/27/2019 | 2     | abc5  |
 | 2/27/2019 | 3     | abc3  |
 -----------------------------
```

I want to take `abc3` from `t1` and then find `abc3` value for `date - 1` day in the same table `t1` and display both records.

In this case it would be 2 records:

```
-------------------------------
| date      | id   |  value   |
-------------------------------
| 2/28/2019 |  3   |  abc3    |
| 2/27/2019 |  3   |  abc3    |
-------------------------------
```

How to achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: Use a self-join, just as you said in the question title.

Comment: It seems like you already know the solution, a self join. You're probably searching for the [`date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function to do the date arithmetic with?

Comment: Do you know how you would do it if they were in different tables? Do it the same way, except the table names are the same.

Comment: Perhaps join using aliases: `select * from tbl a, tbl b where ...`

Comment: @jspcal Please recommend ANSI JOINs. Cross-products are considered archaic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.* 
from t
where value = 'abc3'
order by date desc
limit 2;
```

Or, do you want to *find* `abc3` because the value is the same on two consecutive days?

```
select t.* 
from t
where value = 'abc3' and
      exists (select 1
              from tablename t2
              where t2.value = t.value and
                    t2.date in (t.date - interval 1 day, t.date + interval 1 day) 
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
where
  value = 'abc3'
  and 
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where value = 'abc3' and date in (t.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY, t.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovXAhBhgQLC2hBstDMNcRS/1).